# Mercurial - Rebase branch of old code on top of new code tip, ignoring branch's merges with old code

Tags: mercurial, rebase, transplant

I was playing around with the [Adium](http://www.adium.im/) [source code](http://trac.adium.im/wiki/GettingNewestAdiumSource) and discovered that they had an unreleased branch in the `adium-1.4` that fixes the facebook chat integration by using XMPP, called `facebook-xmpp`. All good there, complied it and it works.

Problem is, if I wanted to have the same functionality in the latest Adium 1.5, whose code got split from the older version's about two years ago (with some changesets from the older version being transplanted over from time to time), I figured I'd have to somehow rebase the entire range of changesets that makes up the `facebook-xmpp` branch and apply it onto the tip of the newer `adium-1.5` branch. I thought this might work since `facebook-xmpp` looks like it mostly adds new code, so it should be easily integrated with the newest development code.

However, since `facebook-xmpp` branch merged with `adium-1.4` several times, I found that rebasing would pull in the merged changes from `adium-1.4` onto `adium-1.5` as well, which makes for a lot of merge conflicts.

```
---------------------------------------  adium-1.4
               |                   \---  facebook-xmpp (created 1 month ago)
               |
               \-----------------------  adium-1.5
               ^ sometime in 2009
```

Question is, is there a way to transplant onto `adium-1.5` only the changesets that added to the `facebook-xmpp` branch, excluding the ones that merged with `adium-1.4` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Method 1 (manual patch)

If you just want the `facebook-xmpp` functionality to be available in `audium-1.5`, you could

1. merge the tip of `audium-1.4` into `facebook-xmpp`, then
2. create a diff between the tips of `audium-1.4` and `facebook-xmpp` and
3. try to apply that patch onto the tip of adium-1.5.

That should work but the new patch is disconnected from the original development history.

```
--------o---o    <- tip of audium-1.4
   \     \   \
    \     o---o  <- tip of facebook-xmpp (all audium-1.4 changes merged in)
     \
      o-------o  <- tip of audium-1.5 (apply patch here)
```

Basically these commands should do it:

```
$ hg up facebook-xmpp
$ hg merge audium-1.4
$ hg commit -m "Merge audium-1.4 into facebook-xmpp"
$ hg diff -r audium-1.4 -r facebook-xmpp > fbx.patch # facebook-only changes
$ hg up audium-1.5
$ hg import fbx.patch # good luck
```

### Method 2 (selective merge)

Another solution, which shows more respect to the history graph, would be to directly merge `facebook-xmpp` into `audium-1.5` while using a [merge tool configuration](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/MergeToolConfiguration) that uses `internal:local` as  the default merge tool (to stop your merge tool from popping up 1000 times) but that merges regularly for any `facebook-xmpp` related files (if your know which files are related to its functionality). Then, before committing the merge, revert all files not related to the facebook thing.

**UPDATE:** Here are some example instructions for this second solution. Supposed the `facebook-xmpp` branch created some new files named `fb-<something>.c` and changed the existing files `foo.c` and `bar.c` (you get these files from a diff between `facebook-xmpp` and its latest merge with `audium-1.4`). When merging `facebook-xmpp` into `audium-1.5`, use the following merge tool configuration:

```
$ hg up audium-1.5
$ hg --config ui.merge=internal:local \
     --config merge-patterns.fb-*.c=internal:merge \
     --config merge-patterns.foo.c=internal:merge \
     --config merge-patterns.bar.c=internal:merge \
     merge facebook-xmpp
```

The first merge config ensures that generally `audium-1.5` changes are kept on files changed in both `audium-1.4` and `audium-1.5`. The other config options ensure that for any files touched by the `facebook-xmpp` branch a regular merge is performed, potentially with conflicts which need to be resolved manually. For instance if `foo.c` raised conflicts, run

```
$ hg resolve foo.c
```

to resolve the conflicts with your favorite manual merge tool. Finally, you have to commit the merge while not committing any new files originating in `audium-1.4`. Just commit the `facebook-xmpp` stuff:

```
$ hg ci -I "fb-*.c" -I foo.c -I bar.c
$ hg up -C # get rid of remaining new files from audium-1.4
```

Comment: sounds pretty good! The second method though, I don't quite get how to make it work, although I understand the idea of it. Specifically, how do I specify which files are related to its functionality (which I don't really know, but just for the sake of argument), how do I make a filter which chooses the merging algorithm? Should I just use merge-patterns for each file/directory?

Comment: @Dan: I just updated the answer with some more detailed instructions for the second method.